# Does a 16x2 LCD display has its own EEPROM?

Tags: lcd

I want to know the ["internal parts of an LCD"](https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=complete+internal+parts+of+16x2+lcd&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiExYTXsrTcAhUHIIgKHTraDNgQ_AUICSgA&biw=1280&bih=677&dpr=1)... but I can't find any from the results.

https://youtu.be/dZZynJLmTn8?t=2m40s @2:40s

"....according to the ASCII"

does that mean ASCII is stored somewhere in the LCD (e.g. ASCII stored in EEPROM) ?

Comment: do you know what ASCII means?

Answer (score 5):

Most displays of this type use [the Hitachi HD44780](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf) LCD controller, or something compatible. The HD44780 stores characters graphics in a 9920-bit mask ROM. (This appears near the bottom of the block diagram on page 3 of the datasheet.)

Some HD44780-compatible graphical LCDs (often sold as the "12864") will read a character table from an EEPROM attached to the back of the LCD. This is necessary because these LCDs support a Chinese font which is too large to store in mask ROM. I've been unable to find an English datasheet for the controller(s?) used on these displays, though.